# What is the relation between JavaSE's `java.sql javax.sql`, and a JDBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc

Are the following two different packages, and neither contains the other?

- a JDBC driver such as `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and
- JavaSE's `java.sql` and `javax.sql`

If I am correct, JavaSE's `java.sql` and `javax.sql` provide `driverManager`, which manages a set of JDBC drivers.
If I am correct, JavaSE's `java.sql` and `javax.sql` provide DBMS-agnostic API. 
Does `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` provide DBMS-specific API?

Which one implements JDBC API? [The definition of JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) is an API, which I understand is DBMS-agnostic, so I guess it is JavaSE's `java.sql` and `javax.sql` which implement JDBC API? Then what API does a JDBC driver implement?

Are JavaSE's `java.sql` and `javax.sql` implemented based on JDBC drivers' APIs?

Is the interface of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` exactly java.sql and javax.sql? Then why no import `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead of importing `java.sql` and `javax.sql`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jdbc DriverManager is implemented by various rdbms drivers, like mysql in this case.  The driver takes care of handling the connection, execution and translation from java types to db types.

Comment: This is wrong, there is only one `DriverManager` implementation, and that is `java.sql.DriverManager`. You are confusing it with the interfaces defined in `java.sql` and `javax.sql` that need to be implemented by a driver.